# Issues implementing SHA256 hash, then pbkdf2Sync and finally cipher with AES-256-cbc - c# to Nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, aes, sha256, pbkdf2

I have been given some c# code which implements SHA256 hashing and then AES-256-cbc. Now I have to translate the same to NodeJS. I tried several option, documentation and question/answers here, but none helped. As I am working with encryption for the first time, possibly something going wrong with encoding - but can't figure out exactly what.
Here is c# implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HelloWorld h1 = new HelloWorld();
        Console.WriteLine(h1.EncryptText("Vitthal", "Vitthal"));
    }
        public string EncryptText(string pInput, string password)
        {
            byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(GenerateSHA256String(pInput));
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
            byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);
            return result;
        }



//  method name GenerateSHA256String and code 


  public string GenerateSHA256String(string inputString)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
                byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(bytes);
                for (int i = 0; i <= hash.Length - 1; i++)
                    stringBuilder.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
                return stringBuilder.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        } 



//  method name AES_Encrypt and code 


 private byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
        {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
            byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    AES.KeySize = 256;
                    AES.BlockSize = 128;

                    var key = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                    AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                    AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
                    AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return encryptedBytes;
        }
}
```

And here is the NodeJS implementation using crypto:

```
const GenerateSHA256String = (object) => {
    const buff = Buffer.from(object.toString());
    const hash = createHash('sha256');
    hash.update(buff);
    const hashed = hash.digest('hex');
    return hashed;
}

const getEncryptedChecksum = (object) => {
    const payload = GenerateSHA256String(object);
    console.log(Buffer.from(payload));
    const passKey = Buffer.from('Vitthal');
    const saltString = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    const key = pbkdf2Sync(GenerateSHA256String(passKey), Buffer.from(saltString), 1000, 100, 'sha1');
    const encKey = key.subarray(0, 32);
    const encIV = key.subarray(32, 48);
    const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encKey, encIV);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(Buffer.from(payload), 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
}

console.log(getEncryptedChecksum('Vitthal'));
```

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved. It was encoding issue. Some strange behaviors different between c# & nodejs. Anyways, here is the final nodejs code that works!

```js
const GenerateSHA256String = (object, encoding) => {
    const buff = Buffer.from(object.toString());
    const hash = createHash('sha256');
    hash.update(buff);
    const hashed = hash.digest(encoding ? encoding : null);
    return hashed;
}

const getEncryptedChecksum = (object) => {
    const payload = GenerateSHA256String(object, 'hex');
    const payBuff = Buffer.from(payload.toUpperCase());
    const passKey = Buffer.from('NDSICDM');
    const saltString = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    const key = pbkdf2Sync(GenerateSHA256String(passKey), Buffer.from(saltString), 1000, 64, 'sha1');
    const encKey = key.subarray(0, 32);
    const encIV = key.subarray(32, 48);
    const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', encKey, encIV);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(payBuff, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
    return encrypted;
}
```